# Why is Hibernate generating a query that joins on the wrong column?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm using Java 1.6, Hibernate 3.1, MySQL 5.5, XML mapping. I have two tables, partner and partner_http_account. I'll just show you the relevant fields.

partner:

```
partnerid dec(22,0) [primary key]
```

partner_http_account:

```
partnerhttpacctid dec(22,0) [primary key]
partnerid dec(22,0) [foreign key]
```

Here's the XML mapping:

```
<class name="com.rc.model.partner.Partner" table="partner" mutable="true">
    <id name="partnerId" type="int">
        <column name="partnerid" scale="10" precision="0" not-null="true" unique="true" sql-type="int unsigned"/>
        <generator class="com.rc.model.jdbc.sequence.MexpIdentifierGenerator">
            <param name="sequence">seq_partnerid</param>
            <param name="idDataType">int</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    ...
    <one-to-one name="partnerHTTPAccount" class="com.rc.model.partner.PartnerHTTPAccount" lazy="false"
                 foreign-key="partnerid" cascade="all"/>
</class>

<class name="com.rc.model.partner.PartnerHTTPAccount" table="partner_http_account">
    <id name="partnerHttpAcctId" type="int">
        <column name="partnerhttpacctid" scale="10" precision="0" not-null="true" unique="true" sql-type="int unsigned"/>
        <generator class="com.rc.model.jdbc.sequence.MexpIdentifierGenerator">
            <param name="sequence">seq_partnerhttpacctid</param>
            <param name="idDataType">int</param>
        </generator>
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="partner" class="com.rc.model.partner.Partner" column="partnerid"
                 foreign-key="partnerid" cascade="none"/>
</class>
```

Here is my Java code:

```
public List<Partner> getPartnersByDomainStartsWith(String domainStartsWith) {

    Query hQuery = sessionManager.getSession().createQuery("from Partner p " +
            "left outer join fetch p.partnerHTTPAccount " +
            "where p.domain like :domainStartsWith||'%'");

    hQuery.setString("domainStartsWith", domainStartsWith);

    return hQuery.list();
}
```

And here is what Hibernate is generating:

```
select partner0_.partnerid as partnerid0_,
partnerhtt1_.partnerhttpacctid as partnerh1_1_,
...
partnerhtt1_.partnerid as partnerid104_1_,
...
from partner partner0_
left outer join partner_http_account partnerhtt1_ on partner0_.partnerid=partnerhtt1_.partnerhttpacctid 
where partner0_.domain like concat(?, '%')
```

My problem is the generated sql query of these two tables is joining on the wrong field. It should join on `partner0.partnerid=partnerhtt1.partnerid` instead. Would really appreciate some insight. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but have you realized that from one side you have a one-to-one relationship and from the other a many-to-one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really well described in the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#assoc-bidirectional-121):

```
<class name="Person">
    <id name="id" column="personId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="address" 
        column="addressId" 
        unique="true"
        not-null="true"/>
</class>

<class name="Address">
    <id name="id" column="addressId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
   <one-to-one name="person" 
        property-ref="address"/>
</class>
```

Notice how property-ref is used, to indicate that the one-to-one is the inverse side of the association mapped by the address property.

Comment: No, it's the reverse. Person contains the join column addressId, which is a foreign key to the Address table. And so does PartnerHTTPAccount, which contains the join column partnerId, which is a foreign key to the Partner table.

Comment: Okay! That works. Thanks. 

I have to say, I don't think anything is well described in the hibernate docs - at least I can never find anything in their examples that seems to map to my situations when I am having trouble - but I appreciate your translating for me.